# Laravel where and how to save a file image

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to web development, and I am developing, client registration with photos in **Laravel**, I was able to send my form and my photo via ajax request to my controller, but now I have the following:

- I better not live in any database or in folders?
- If I choose to save to folders, how do I do this? according to a
  structure that laravel brings me which is the local ideal for me to
  save?

Search Engine Code:

```
if($ request-> hasFile ('UploadIMG'))
{

   $ image = $ request->file('UploadIMG');
   $ fileName = time (). '.' . $ image->getClientOriginalExtension ();

   $ img = Image :: make ($ image->getRealPath ());
   $ img-> resize (120, 120, function ($ constraint) {
   $ constraint->aspectRatio ();
});

$ img-> stream (); // <- Key point    
}
```

How do I define a mass where this image will be saved?

Comment: Save the actual file in a folder in something like `resources/uploads`, `storage/uploads` or `public/uploads`, ect etc, and save a reference to the file's URL in the database where required. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem Should have all the information you need to accomplish this.

Comment: When you say URL is literally the way to access it? so when I go to an edit or show screen is it just me putting that URL in the img's SRC? or should I leave it in a non-public place and whenever I want to access this image I should send the controller to view

Comment: The way I've done it is uploading it into a custom folder of `resources/uploads/images`, which is linked to a config option in `config/filesystems.php`, and a symlink to a folder in `public` so you can access the images via `myapp/images/1234.png` (assuming that `myapp/` is your project root, set to `public`), then save that url (or part of the url) in the database

Comment: do I have to create a symbolic link for storage? 
if you can help with some example

Comment: You don't _have_ to, but I would. You could always store your files directly in `public/images`, but that means than anything uploaded would be publicly accessible, even non-image files like `.exe`, unless you validate uploads throughly. And I'm afraid I don't have a hard example I can provide, just the steps to handle it.