# Display the folder image for the view Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I access a direct image from storage?

I'm saving the images from my project in `storage/images/clients/` how do I retrieve those images and display them for the view?

Comment: This seems to be a follow-up to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48171822/laravel-where-and-how-to-save-a-file-image; be sure to either close/delete that question if it's not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a symbolic link between the `storage/images` and `public/images`:

```
ln -s /full/path/to/storage/images /full/path/to/public/images
```

Then you'll be able to use these images:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/clients/john.jpg') }}">
```

Comment: How do I create this link? how does it work? No need to create the route?

Comment: @BrunoSilva use the `ln` command as I've shown. No, you don't need to create a route.

Comment: I better create the symbolic link or already save the image in the public folder?

Comment: @BrunoSilva it's better to keep files in the `storage` directory and create a symbolic link.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to implement your answer and I'll come back to give you okay if you do not have any doubts

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the raw content of the file use:

```
$contents = Storage::get('/path/to/file.jpg');
```

But if you just trying to display it in the view, there no need for any special cumbersome method, Simply use

```
<img src="/path/to/file.jpg">
```