# PHP Laravel video file upload

Tags: laravel, video, uploading

I'm trying upload video in laravel. When it does upload it, it keeping saving file as php3d58.tmp and not mp4. Help me? I've been trying since yesterday and I've got nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`storeAs()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#file-uploads) method to save uploaded file and  `getClientOriginalExtension()` to get original file extension:

```
$path = $request->file('video')->storeAs(
    'videos_directory',
    $request->file('video')->getClientOriginalName() . '.' . $request->file('video')->getClientOriginalExtension()
);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, But its not working. Can you tell me why its saving as php3d58.tmp and not mp4?

Comment: @StephanyRocks what exactly doesn't work? Do you get an error?

Comment: Yes something about save as() method. But let me Show you what I have first. This is my code am I doing something wrong?

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App\User;

class FileController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function store(Request $request){

     $file=$request->file('file');
     $filename=time() . '.' .$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
     $destinationpath=storage_path('/introvideo',$filename);
     $file->getPathName();
     $file->move($destinationpath);
     $user=Auth::user();
     $user->profilepicture=$file=$filename;
     $user->save();




   


    }


}

Comment: @StephanyRocks looks like you literally used `$request->file('video')`. But it's just an example. Use `$request->file('file')` instead of `$request->file('video')`.

Comment: public function store(Request $request){

     $path = $request->file('file')->storeAs(
    'videos_directory',
    $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName() . '.' . $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension()
);
     $user=Auth::user();
     $user->profilepicture=$file=$path;
     $user->save();




   


    }

Comment: But its not storing in the directory folder

Comment: how do i move it to the folder?

Comment: The code will save the video to `videos_directory` directory. Change it to any other directory you want to save to.

Comment: OK. One last thing i want to display the video on the screen how do i do that? This is how i want to display it     <div class="" style="border:1px solid blue;"><video><source src="{{Auth::}}"></source></video></div>
 but what do i put for the source?

Comment: To be able to do that, you need to [create a symbolic link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48176373/1227923) between `storage/your_video_directory` and `public/your_video_directory`. Then you'll be able to display the video on a web page with something like `<source src="{{ asset('your_video_directory/example_video.mp4') }}">`

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry to keep asking you all these questions but i'm having another issues the image saves to the directory but its saved as php8F1C.php while on the database it saves as introvideo/islands2.mp4. So how am I supposed to display it?

Comment: @StephanyRocks when you use `storeAs()` as I've shown, the file will be stored with the name you've defined. You can check the documentation on [file uploading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#file-uploads)

Comment: storeAs() is not saving the file name but as tmp file. What do I do? I really need you to guide me in this. I have a big project to complete on this and you  seem like the only person helping me.

Comment: @StephanyRocks I'm sorry, but I don't know why it doesn't work. `storeAs()` always worked for me. I think you need to create a new question and explain there what exactly happens when you're uploading a file. Maybe someone will be able to help with that.

Comment: Omg!! I see that it works Thank you Thank you Thank you!!!!... But I cant display the video on the screen its not showing. I used     <div class="" style="border:1px solid blue;"><video height="300" autoplay controls><source  alt="video not playing" src="{{ asset('/introvideo' .$pro->profilepicture) }}"><source></video></div>