# Laravel - How to revert local storage symlink and refresh

Tags: laravel, storage, symlink

When I save images to storage they show in the **storage/app** directory, but they don't show in **public/storage**. I also noticed that a **storage/app/public** directory seems to have been created which also contains everything within storage/app.

I can't work out how I managed to cause this mess, and I think it might make sense to revert these directories to how it should have been to begin with (with a new laravel project), remove any existing symlinks, and start again - does this sound like the best approach? And how would I go about doing this if I have set the symlink up incorrectly?

Comment: For anyone coding in Windows environment - check this post: http://laravel.at.jeffsbox.eu/laravel-5-gotchas-symbolic-link-symlink

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can always delete the link:

```
cd public
rm storage
```

And create a new one without using the `storage:link` command if you need to link different locations:

```
\File::link(storage_path('dir1'), public_path('dir2'));
```

Or [create a symlink manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48176373/1227923):

```
ln -s /full/path/to/storage/dir1 /full/path/to/public/dir2
```

Answer (score 12):

I had this problem and I fixed it by adding this to my deployment script:

```
cd public
rm storage
cd ..
php artisan storage:link
```

Before you do that, you can SSH into your deployment server and navigate to the `/public` folder. You might see a `storage` folder in there, and you should notice it's a symlink. You should leave it there and add my above commands to your deployment script.

If you remove storage link manually, you'll need to skip these on the first deployment:

```
cd public
rm storage
cd ..
```

Then every deployment after, you can do:

```
cd public
rm storage
cd ..
php artisan storage:link
```

If you don't do that, your deployment will fail probably because if `rm storage` throws an error, it will fail the build. Pay close attention to what I'm saying. You must be very specific when doing CLI commands, unless you can add some bash script that handles the 2 cases where `./public/storage` exists (1) and when it doesn't (2).

You might gloss over my mention about deleting the `storage` symlink reference manually, but don't forget that if you deployment script does it and then fails for another reason, the symlink will `be gone`.

Someone should post an answer that uses a bash script to ensure both cases can be handled. I don't have the skill for that.

> **NOTE:** `php artisan storage:link` only works while you are in the root directory of your project. That's why my above script starts with `cd public` and why it does `cd ..`. If you aren't in the root at the time, the `php artisan` command will fail.

Answer (score 6):

**Simple Way**

Go to public folder Just delete/remove the storage link inside public/

**Then Run the command**

```
    php artisan storage:link
```

the above command will link storage again

Answer (score 5):

That is actually how it should be! Laravel has a command to symlink your public directory to the storage directory:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

The idea is to keep a persistent storage between deployments.

> This convention will keep your publicly accessible files in one
>   directory that can be easily shared across deployments when using zero
>   down-time deployment systems like Envoyer.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem

Comment: I don't think this is available in Laravel 5.1

Comment: Doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 3):

For windows users, I have tested this with Windows 10 and Laravel 7

Steps:

1. cd to your `<project_root>/public` directory and run `rmdir storage` - it will remove the link
2. cd back to project root directory and run `php artisan storage:link` to link again

The links should now be refreshed and viewable without issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan storage:link --force
```