# laravel 8 not showing freshly added images while it show old image

Tags: laravel, file-upload, local-storage, laravel-8, image-upload

i already run command php artisan storage:link

it shows only old images while when i upload new image in storage folder it does not appear while that image is exist on that location.

this is the image that won't show

[image]

and this that image file that i uploaded 7_587597.jpg but it don't shows while old files are showing while newly added doesn't show

[image]

Comment: Post blade file where you’re showing image and your controller where you’re sending to view. Try php artisan optimize:clear as well

Comment: already do this thing

Comment: but this method work for me 

cd public
rm storage
cd ..
php artisan storage:link

Comment: solution for this problem 
cd public

rm storage

cd ..

php artisan storage:link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510683/laravel-how-to-revert-local-storage-symlink-and-refresh#new-answer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the parsing of Blade files on each reload, Laravel caches the views after Blade is processed. I've experienced some situations where the source (view file) is updated but the cache file is not "reloaded". In these cases, all you need to do is to delete the cached views and reload the page.

The cached view files are stored in storage/framework/views.