# symlink to subfolder in example.com/laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url, symlink

I have installed Laravel 5.5 in subfolder on root of my shared hosting example.com/laravel and now I am creating symlink by `php artisan storage:link` via putty (terminal window) and got this error:

`The symlink (): No such file or directory`

How can I properly maintain a link to laravel project installed on example.com/laravel and when I later deploy it to other domain what parameters should be changed?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the directory to make the command work:

```
storage/app/public
```

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#the-public-disk):

> By default, the `public` disk uses the local driver and stores these files in `storage/app/public`. To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`

Also, make sure permissions are set correctly.

If you want to link any custom directories, [create the symlink manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48176373/1227923).

Comment: you mean i have to careate public on following direcotory public_html/myproject/storage?

Comment: i have created the storage folder under public_html/myproject/ but command didn't work

Comment: @JahanAhmedAbbasi if the whole Laravel project is in `public_html`, the command will work. If not, you'll need to [create the symlink manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48176373/1227923).

Comment: @JahanAhmedAbbasi use the `ln` command like `ln -s /full/path/to/public_html/myproject/storage/app/public /full/path/to/public_html/myproject/public/storage/`

Comment: my main project is not in public_html only the public folder is in public_html and the remaining folders are in root (sibling to public_html)