# Laravel 5.6 How to do save images correctly on storage

Tags: php, laravel, file, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I want to save my images storage. But there are some errors about that.

**Here is my codes in controller;**

```
if ($request->hasFile('site_logo')) {
     $image = $request->file('site_logo');
     $realname = pathinfo($request->file('site_logo')->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
     $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
     $new_name = $realname."-".time().$extension;
     $image->storeAs('public/uploads', $new_name);
     $path = Storage::url($new_name);
     $settings->site_logo = $new_name;
     $settings->site_logo_path = $path;
     $settings->site_logo_alt_name = $realname;
    }
```

**Database records;**

```
site_logo | /tmp/phpqTLyXY
site_logo_path | /storage/1518975452-logo.png
site_logo_alt_name | logo
```

**Questions;**

1- Why site_logo can't get `$new_name` instead "/tmp/phpqTLyXY" ?

2- `$path` says "/storage/1518975452-logo.png" is image url. But When I said "project.app/storage/1518975452-logo.png" it says "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found." it can't found image ?

Sorry for bad english knowledge :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [create a symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48176373/1227923):

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Then you'll be able to access the image with:

```
project.app/storage/uploads/image_name.png
```

Comment: Yess, When I add manually "uploads" to links, it works, but still $path doesn't give me the correct link. It gives "storage/logo.png" not the "storage/uploads/logo.png" :/

Comment: @cervantes you need to do this if you want to get correct path `Storage::url('uploads/' . $new_name);`

Comment: this time `uploads` seems but `$new_name` disappeared  ->> Recording like    "/storage/uploads/"

Comment: @cervantes this means this time `$new_name` was empty.

Comment: I checked with `dd()` method, it's not empty

Comment: @cervantes well, `Storage::url('uploads/' . 'some_file_name.png')` will always give you `storage/uploads/some_file_name.png`

Comment: wait a minute.. it's a dot not a comma! -_-. Thanks, finally works :)

Comment: also, do you have any idea about `site_logo`, why it cant get `$new_name`